# how best can I do a global quantitative analysis of an videos frame color

Tags: image, video, image-processing, colors, video-processing

I am trying to analyse an mp4 video and convert it's video content into some sort of array of numbers. where the numbers would represent the "global" color of the frame.
The frames are essentially grayscale frames.
Eventually would like to analyse the frequency of a the lightest global color in the image.

Can anyone suggest the best (simplest) solution?
Thanks very much for looking and any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried looking into [OpenCV[1](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), the computer vision library?

It has [support for many video formats](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) such as mp4.

The [histogram functionality](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_histograms.html) sounds very close to what you want.

I'm not sure what you mean by lightest color (does that mean lowest saturation in HSV color space?) etc. There's plenty of color space conversion and other functionality that you can explore in OpenCV.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the link... I'm definately going to go this way.. by lightest color, I mean whitest.. I'm more or less trying to find the frequency of a blinking light in a video...

Comment: You're welcome. You can probably convert to grayscale and just pick the highest intensity.